# Typescript: Having problems with mapping nested Record values wrapped in vue3 reactive proxy

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, typescript-generics

UPDATED VERSION:

I have several implementations of a generic class, which is wrapped in the vue3 composition api function "**reactive**", which is basically a proxy which keeps track of any updates:

```js
export declare function reactive<T extends object>(target: T): UnwrapNestedRefs<T>;
```

How can I implement a class so that the constructor takes an object of such implementations, and have such inner types unwrapped as parameter of a callback function which is the second argument of the constructor?

Like this:

```js
const campaignWrapped = reactive(new MyWrapper<Campaign>(campaign));
const batchesWrapped = reactive(new MyWrapper<Batch[]>(batches));

new MyClass({ first: campaignWrapped, second: batchesWrapped }, (states) => {
    states.first; // Should be of type Campaign
    states.second; // Should be of type Batch[]
  });
```

It seems like it's not possible to derive the type from the proxy object, because `extends MyClass<infer U> ? ...` doesn't match anymore. The only way around seems to be adding an interface to the Class and check for this interface instead. Even if I unwrap UnwrapNestedRefs first and infer it's type, I still can't get the real inner type.

---

OLD VERSION: (simplified)

*(just for the context, as my wrong attempt might help someone to understand the difference between union and intersect - which wasn't clear to me)*

I want to get the unboxed types in a callback, which have to be derived from generic types.

So far so good. It seems to work if I have only one record entry.

But as soon as there is another, it fails.

The resulting type looks ALMOST correct:

`Record<"first", Campaign> | Record<"second", Batch[]>`

How can I tell typescript to use intersect and not union? So the type would become:

`Record<"first", Campaign> & Record<"second", Batch[]>`

(BONUS QUESTION: Is it possible to get rid of the LSW interface and use the type of the class directly? For me the `extends LazyStateWrapper<infer U> ? ...` didn't work.)

[Working example in typescriptlang.org playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-wroXaJ1Hm7js4oLIDAZbOV2BwoCzhtOoAAhEJ6TMF1esdd2TfboZQY4oJCHljH0-DVT3MwUxzmAC5LrYs7zouy4dmutgAIwAEwAMzEHuB5QNSFDUn+AHRpMH7ALeEDAteRGZg0zQFpR-4qIBZogWBcBQmAkDtvw2AIOI-jgtsLERAUeiMdBTJ4Q8743pmJH8diBacdxmwQjJ8aEcR9CiZy9FQECwDwXJEBcYsKDLKscDrDx1oFKumJIMwthCVBS4ye2LLEACnzwgGXZRuJFAgAWHxAqSNnME4UAAPThVAACaKAgKSUCSEYADW9AAIRQOgRyyNp4DQAARJBoHQfl6Y+fQxJkhSVJ+Rp3k9sAfYDs2rZ6mWGliUBOmIfphlLCsaxWhCVm7qwtnAPZwlObatDEPQ+iEk+qlSfQzmnm5gUkZ5HZlVpfkBRCuYhcAYWRVAAAiBgkXAtJQAgKXDnAIBukYEDEISAraVJPbDj9L0-T2KQMAll6PJMrxQN6X3QBeFIGKlUZIIDwAJQAoto2gAPLaLYAAKSAGBEoCYcdOH0iRdgGJMlA5pMhK5R41LJEYJj5cd+XEEVTE8CizOpPl833LQHNXpJlFcNSCX44TODE9SpNQOTjBwFTQi0+KA4XkzC384Li0i2Rt7i5LBQochACc3S7dGlXkpSBS1ZG3a9v22otrq2LtU4QA)

And here is the code inline:

```js
type UnwrapInner<X, S extends string> = X extends LSW<infer X>
  ? Record<S, X>
  : never;

type UnwrapLazyStateWrapper<T> = T extends Record<infer S, infer U> ? (S extends string ? UnwrapInner<T[S], S> : never) : never;

export class TransientLazyState<X, T extends object> {
  constructor(states: X, cb: (states: UnwrapLazyStateWrapper<X>) => T | undefined) {
    console.log('todo');
  }
}

interface LSW<T extends object> {
  getStateClone(): T | undefined;
}

export class LazyStateWrapper<T extends object> implements LSW<T> {
  private obj: T;
  constructor(instance: T) {
    this.obj = instance;
  }

  getStateClone(): T | undefined {
    return {} as T;
  }
}

type Campaign = { id: number; foo: string };
type Batch = { id: number; bar: string };

const campaign: Campaign = { id: 123, foo: 'x' };
const batches: Batch[] = [];

const campaignWrapped = new LazyStateWrapper(campaign);
const batchesWrapped = new LazyStateWrapper(batches);

const test1 = new TransientLazyState({ first: campaignWrapped }, (states) => {
    const xy = states.first; // Yay. Works! Is of type "Campaign"
    console.log(xy);
    return undefined;
  });

const test2 = new TransientLazyState({ first: campaignWrapped, second: batchesWrapped }, (states) => {
    const xy = states.first; // Doesn't work anymore, once there are more records. But to me the type looks ALMOST correct. ERROR: Property 'first' does not exist on type 'Record<"first", Campaign> | Record<"second", Batch[]>'. Property 'first' does not exist on type 'Record<"second", Batch[]>'.(2339)
    console.log(xy);
    return undefined;
  });
```

Comment: There's a lot going on in that code... if your question can be reduced to "why can't I access the `first` property of `Record<"first", Campaign> | Record<"second", Batch[]>`", then the answer is "because unions are *either* / *or*, not *both* / *and*"... that's an intersection.  So you probably want `Record<"first", Campaign> & Record<"second", Batch[]>` instead.

Comment: Please consider [asking only one primary question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741/511366).  You have asked "why is it complaining", "how can I get this working", and a bonus question.  You might want to rephrase so that you are clearly looking for a single answer to a single question.  You're always free to post a new question if the answer to the primary question doesn't clear up your secondary ones.

Comment: You're right. Apparently "&" instead of "|" would work. (And I think I start to understand why. I had something twisted up in my head) ... But how to tell typescript that those possible types derived from the input should be intersected?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NnXDxW) meet your needs? If so, please [edit] the question to remove `UnwrapInner`, `UnwrapLazyStateWrapper`, and `LSW`, and ask something more appropriate like "how can I implement `TransientLazyState` so that the constructor takes two arguments of the form etc etc".  If your primary question is "how can I get this to work", then the broken version is just a distraction.  If it doesn't meet your needs, can you elaborate on what's missing?

Comment: Thank you! It does help a lot. It doesn't work out of the box, because the LazyStateWrapper is wrapped in reactive(), which is vue3 code and wraps it in type UnwrapNestedRefs. But if I keep using the LSW interface somehow I can get it to work in my real code as well and I am soooo happy about it! ((It was a very long day of ~15h working and my head is about to explode. I will read your instructions carefully again tomorrow and will update the ticket accordingly. For now I need to take a break - and sleep peacefully thanks to your help!))